# How should I use 哟?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word, particles

Here is the conversation with my Chinese friend:

> I: I passed the application!
>
> She: 你申请过啦
>
> She: 恭喜**哟**

According to Pleco:

> 哟
>
> 1. [at the end of an imperative sentence]
> 2. [as a syllable filler in a song]

And it also writes:

> 1 (sentence-final particle expressing exhortation)

But the *exhortation* sounds awkward in this context (why does she have to urge me to do something?). So

- How 哟 should be used in the conversation?
- What kind of nuances it has?
- Depending on the sentence ending with or without 哟, what differences would the reader (local) get?

Comment: This is Sichuanese isn’t it? Perhaps more specifically Chongqingese if I recall correctly.

Comment: @user3306356 She is Hangzhounese. You mean my older post? She is a different friend.

Comment: Oh okay, my bad. If it were Sichuanese there'd be a very different answer to this question.

Comment: @user3306356 How is it different? Feel free to add an answer as it would be informative.

Comment: see grammar on interjections (叹词) e.g. ＂实用现代汉语语法＂ https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/23215/how-do-chinese-speakers-convey-emotions-by-speech

哟／yo／，表示轻微的惊异（有时带有玩笑的语气）。例如：哟，挂住我的‌​衣服了。(哟 also occurs in the compounds 哎哟、喔哟)

Comment: （comment #5 is about 呦 at the beginning of an utterance in which case it is an interjection(叹词），Q concerns end of sentence in which case it is a modal particle(语气助词）cf.＂汉英虚词词典＂ 呦 yo 表示感叹或祈使的语气，有时可用于疑问句尾：expresses an exclamatory or imperative sense, and sometimes may be used at the end of an interrogative sentence:１。惠施～！你是我唯一的知已！（郭沫若［漆园史游梁］）２。小姑娘点头道：＂是～，是～！（杨佩瑾［霹雳］）３。她噗嗤一声，笑了：＂憨老汉～！。。。＂（贾平凹［选不掉］）４。老马同志啊！你现在哪里～？（海默［我的引路人］）５。你可不能这么糊涂～！６。你们快来看～！水仙开花了！

Comment: ＂汉语８００虚词用法词典＂哟（助）用于句尾，表示祈使的语气，含有提醒、催促、感叹的语义。（１）明星们走出来了，快来看哟！（２）我们玩儿得好开心哟！（３）快拉我一把哟！（４）快帮帮我哟！我提不动了。（５）大家都站好了，我要照了，笑一笑哟！好。（６）你来做哟！我还不会用这个电高压锅。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 恭喜哟
>
> But the exhortation sounds awkward in this context (why does she have to urge me to do something?).

Beside expressing exhortation '哟' also emphasizes the topic and add an earnest tone to the phrase.

恭喜 (flat, plain)

恭喜哟 (passionate, keen)

> How 哟 should be used in the conversation?

As dictionary defined, 哟 is a final particle that expressing exhortation

過馬路要小心 Be careful when crossing the street

過馬路要小心(哟) Be careful when crossing the street (I meant it!)

> What kind of nuances it has?

It is similar to exclamation like 'please!' , 'really!' in English

> Depending on the sentence ending with or without 哟, what differences would the reader (local) get?

See the example in this post

Comment: I see. Thanks. But then what is the difference from 呀, which I feel more familiar with and can be used like the exclamation point in English?

Comment: And is it used both in written and spoken context?

Comment: 呀 as a final particles, can emphasize the topic,  and depend on the topic, it also adds 'commanding, affirmative or assertive tone to the sentence . In ' 過馬路要小心呀!' , '呀' add an assertive tone to it, make it sound like a command, Final particles are more commonly used in colloquial language than written language.

Answer (score 2):

**哟** in Sichuanese has slightly different connotations:

> 《成都方言》
>
> 词语: 哟
>
> 发音: yuo2
>
> 定义: 叹词，表示惊异、不满等：啥子（东西）～？

Expressing astonishment and/or dissatisfaction.

> 《广安方言与民俗词典》
>
> 词语: 哟
>
> 发音: yuo2
>
> 定义: ①用于疑问句或感叹句末，表示反问、责问、不以为然或不满等。例：你在搞啥子～？②表示否定语气。例：我还不晓得哟！以否定语气表示说“我晓得”。

Carrying a somewhat disapproving tone for reproving-like questioning.

Or expressing "as if I didn't know" -or- "duh"-type negation.

Answer (score 1):

[哟 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%96%B2)

The pronunciation for "哟" is not just "yo", but it could be spelled like this:

> yō, yāo, yōu

According  to Wiktionary, it means an exclamation when one feels surprised on something. I think it's pretty much the same as "呀", e.g. "哎呀" and "哎哟" are the same thing, so both "哟" and "呀" can be interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

To augment the other answers, 哟 sounds too cutie to my ear. I only say it when I try to pretend to be girly. But it could be different in the areas of TWN and HK.

Comment: She is a HS girl.

Answer (score -3):

It is always used in the end of a sentence as a modal particle.